# Can't install Cura 3.1 to my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, updates, dependencies

I am trying to download Cura slicer software to my computer and I keep getting stopped dead in my tracks. I have tried `sudo apt update`     and I get this message:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'sp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I have tried to install with

```
sudo apt-get install cura
```

but then I get :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cura : Depends: python3-uranium but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qml-module-qtqml-models2 but it is not installable
        Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls but it is not installable
        Depends: qml-module-qtquick-dialogs but it is not installable
        Recommends: cura-resources-firmware but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: cura-plugins-all but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: python3-numpy-stl but it is not installable
N: Ignoring file 'sp' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:thopiekar/cura
```

but it tells me: `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

I am new to linux and only have little experience. Please explain what you are trying to tell me in layman terms. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To format commands you typed that are in the middle of other text, surround it with `\``s. To format terminal output, select it and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: For `ppa-purge` to work, it has to be installed.   `sudo apt install ppa-purge`

Comment: You have messed your repositories or dependencies. Did `apt-get install -f` or `dpkg --configure -a` help? Please update your question with output of the following command `grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep deb` (it will all enabled repositories).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current stable version of Cura is available by PPA:  [ppa:thopiekar/cura](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/cura):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/cura
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install cura
```

If you want a bleeding edge version of Cura - you can use [ppa:thopiekar/cura-master](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/cura-master)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/cura-master
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cura
```

Comment: I did a clean install and it fixed ALL of my problems, Including facebook wouldn't play video on Firefox and Spotify not being able to play music.

Comment: this repo has only cura 2.7 and latest now is 3.4.

Comment: @Kostanos Find new PPA by yourself and share link here. Please.

Comment: nah, just download it from their site: https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software
and run it

Answer (score 2):

The repository mentioned in accepted answer is out of date, it has only 2.7 version of cura. Currently the better way to install it, is to download it from [cura site](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software) directly.

```
wget https://download.ultimaker.com/current/Cura-3.4.1.AppImage
sudo mv Cura-3.4.1.AppImage /usr/bin/cura
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/cura
```

Now you can just run `cura`